# Error creating JClouds SwiftApi: Provider org.jclouds.openstack.keystone.v2_0.KeystoneApiMetadata could not be instantiated

Tags: java, jclouds

I have some code for connecting to a JClouds swift storage container which works fine in its own test area, but once I integrate into my project, I get an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
>   org.jclouds.apis.ApiMetadata: Provider
>   org.jclouds.openstack.keystone.v2_0.KeystoneApiMetadata could not be
>   instantiated: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

This is the code which fails on the ContextBuilder line:

```
private SwiftApi swiftApi;

public JCloudsConnector(String username, String password, String endpoint) {
      String provider = "openstack-swift";

      Properties overrides = new Properties();
      overrides.setProperty("jclouds.mpu.parallel.degree", "" + Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

      swiftApi = ContextBuilder.newBuilder(provider)
            .endpoint(endpoint)
            .credentials(username, password)
            .overrides(overrides)
            .buildApi(SwiftApi.class);
}
```

I am using the same dependencies (JClouds version 1.7.3) so I can't understand what the problem might be since both are run in the same environment.

Comment: Which version of Guava do you have in the classpath? Also, which version of the JVM are you running?

Comment: Guava is at 16.0.1 and JVM 1.7.051

Comment: Jclouds 1.7.3 depends on Guava 15.0 and won't work with greater versions in that version of the JVM. Can you stick to Guava 15.0?

Comment: Thanks so much! The problem is fixed now.

Comment: Don't put SOLVED in the title of your questions, or answer your questions in the question.  Post a separate answer instead, and mark it completed by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Ignasi Barrera, I was able to sort this by adding an entry for Guava 15.0 in my maven POM file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>15.0</version>
</dependency>
```